# Hijicking a key combination in vue

Tags: vue.js, events, event-handling, dom-events

I am trying to capture <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> on my keyboard

`v-on:keyup.shift.56.prevent="dosomething"`

It calls the method fine but also outputs the standard symbol `*`. Can I stop the output from displaying this?

Comment: Maybe you can try `@keydown.shift.56.prevent` if `keyup` is not an absolute necessity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-on:keydown.shift.56.capture.prevent.stop="dosomething"`

Seem like preventing on keydown before the key is rendered on screen works. Obvious really.